# Exchange 2010 remove Arbitration mailbox and mailbox store db

Tags: exchange

I have a problem with Exchange 2010 which is a nightmare for me. The problem is, that in Exchange management console i have several store databases in database management tab. only one is mounted, because i am using it. the second one is mounted, but it was used on other server before (now that server is dead). that database mounted status is UNKNOWN. The file of that database does not exist, but it still shows there. I can't remove it from management console, because it has mailboxes. i removed all mailboxes and disabled two arbitrary mailboxes. i can't delete it because i still have one arbitrary mailbox left. i can't move it, because it requires connection to dead server. i can't disable it, because i get error that it is the last one in organization.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: sorry the question. I am working with exchange problems for 30 hours without sleep. i just found the solution: `Get-Mailbox -Arbitration -Database db1 | Remove-Mailbox -Arbitration -RemoveLastArbitrationMailboxAllowed`

Answer (score 4):

The answer according to the OP:

> I found the solution:
>
> ```
> Get-Mailbox -Arbitration -Database db1 | Remove-Mailbox -Arbitration -RemoveLastArbitrationMailboxAllowed
> ```